# Passing a struct pointer to a function in C

Tags: c, function, structure

I'm having trouble passing a struct to a function that takes a struct pointer as an argument and keep getting the error "error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘StackNode’)"

Here's the necessary portions of my code (not all of it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackNode{
    char data;
    struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;

void convertToPostfix(char infix[], char postfix[]);
int isOperator(char c);
int precedence(char operator1, char operator2);
void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, char value);
char pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr);
char stackTop(StackNodePtr topPtr);
int isEmpty(StackNodePtr topPtr);
void printStack(StackNodePtr topPtr);

int main(){
    convertToPostfix(NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void convertToPostfix(char infix[], char postfix[]){
    StackNode stack = {'(', NULL};
    push(*stack, 'a');
    printStack(&stack);
}

void push(StackNodePtr* topPtr, char value){
    topPtr->nextPtr = NULL; //just temporary, not needed
    topPtr->data = value; //just temporary, not needed
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Change the `push` call, `push(*stack, 'a')`:

```
push(&stack, 'a');
     ^
```

Indirection on `stack` (`*`) makes no sense since it's not a pointer. Taking its address (`&`) does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works as long as I remove the extra * from my push method, however is

Answer (score 4):

Since StackNodePtr is already a pointer to StackNode you don't need more '*' in argument list.

Replace all

```
void push(StackNodePtr* topPtr, char value){ // WRONG
                     ^^^
```

to

```
void push(StackNodePtr topPtr, char value){ // RIGHT
                     ^^^
```

Comment: Yep, you're right, and as **cnicutar** noticed, **nain33** tries to dereference struct instead of getting a pointer to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your compiler is being clever.  It knows that a void pointer (NULL) is not the same thing as a StackNodePtr.   You need a cast on the call or a definition of a null stacknode pointer value.

```
NULLSNP=(StackNodePtr)NULL;
```

As another post said, the call to push is also wrong, it should be & not &.

```
push(&stack, 'a');
```

The definition of push and pop is wrong, you give it a stacknodeptr but expect  a stacknodeptr pointer.

```
void push(StackNodePtr topPtr, char value)
char pop(StackNodePtr topPtr);
```

Comment: Actually in C `NULL` can be assigned uncasted to any pointer: the initializer is fine.